# How does converting/determining column widths in the jsPDF library work when exporting DATA GRID from devexpress?

Tags: angular, devexpress, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF with `<dx-data-grid` from devexpress.

To export the table to PDF, I call the `exportDataGrid()` method and repeat the steps as described in the documentation and example. (link: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/PDFOverview/Angular/Light/)

But I don’t understand how the column width in the table on the monitor screen is converted to the width on the A4 sheet?

Here's an example: a table has 8 columns, and the page orientation is landscape. In the table in the demo, you can see that the text in the cells does not fit in the table (and an ellipsis "..." is added). But after converting to PDF, I see that everything fits.

[image: GridToPDF]

In the devexpress docs, I found only information that I can set the width of the columns units of measurement specified in the constructor of the jsPDFDocument object.

So, how does the conversion work in the case I described? Is there a link to documentation where I can read about it?